# How to create a new table in R markdown from an existing table in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a shiny app that outputs the following table:

|  | France |
| --- | --- |
| **Population (m)** | 67 |
| **Size (km)** | 543940 |
| **No. of cities** | 85 |
| **Average temperature (summer)** | 20 |
| **Average temperature (winter)** | 5 |
| **No. of airports** | 464 |

Server code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data <- matrix(c(input$pop, input$size, input$city, temp_sum(a,b), 
temp_win(a,b), airport(a), ncol = 1,byrow = T)

colnames(data) <- input$country

rownames(data) <- c("Population (m)", "Size (km)", "No. of cities", 
"Average temperature (summer)", "Average temperature (winter)", "No. of 
airports")

output$table <- renderTable(data,rownames = TRUE)
```

I am trying to get this table to display in a report that can be generated from the shiny app using a r markdown file. However I only want the data for the last three rows to be displayed which are based on functions I defined earlier in shiny and I want this in the below format:

|  | Average temperature (summer) | Average temperature (winter) | No. of airports |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **France** | 20 | 5 | 464 |

I am unsure how I would do this and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~name, ~France,
  "population", 67,
  "no of cities", 85,
  "avg temp summer", 5,
  "avg temp winter", 5,
  "no airports", 464
)

data %>%
  tail(3) %>%
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "country") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   country `avg temp summer` `avg temp winter` `no airports`
#>   <chr>               <dbl>             <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 France                  5                 5            464
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You might want to use `data <- data %>% column_to_rownames("name")` before if you do not have a tibble, but just a `data.frame`.